# open new window with javascript and send POST parameters

Tags: javascript

I would like to open a new window with javascript and pass POST parameters to it. I've tried a lot of things.

My latest code looks like this so far, but not working (I haven't tried to pass post parameters but after it will work I can only add hidden input to make it work. I guess.):

```
<form method="POST" name="showgraph" onsubmit="javascript:window.open('graph.php', 'Graph', 'scrollbars=yes,titlebar=no,top=300,left=400');" action="javascript:void(0)">
<a href="#" onClick="document.showgraph.submit();">Show graph</a>
</form>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript post request like a form submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit)

Comment: Replace `action="javascript:"` with `action="graph.php"`, remove `onsubmit=...` and add `target="Graph"`. The form will be opened in a new tab/window, depending on the user's preference.

Comment: I need to open it in new WINDOW.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create hidden form with `target="_blank"` and submit it with javascript. It is not  possible to pass `POST` parameters using `window.open`  method. For more details visit this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit)

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the initial page, why not just creat JavaScript variables with PHP?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php

foreach ($_POST as $key => $val)
{
    echo "var php_$key = $val;";
}

?>
</script>
```

Then, you can pass the js vars in the query string of the URL parameter of `window.open`.